# ggplot legend - how to change the colour spread?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, raster

I would like to change the spread display of the legend bar as on the jpeg below. In example 1, I'd like to display the "100" threshold value in the middle of the legend bar. In example 2, I'd like to display the mean value (white colour) in the middle of the legend bar. I suspect both would require similar line of code. Could someone very kindly help me with this?

```
#library
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

#sample raster
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18)
r[] <- (-ncell(r)/2+1):(ncell(r)/2)
r[1,] <- 5000
plot(r)

var_df <- as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(r))

### example 1
p <- ggplot() 
p <- p + geom_raster(data = var_df , aes(x = x, y = y, fill = layer))
p <- p + coord_equal()
p <- p + scale_fill_gradientn(
  colours=c("red", "yellow", "skyblue", "darkblue"),
  values = rescale(c(min(var_df$layer),
                     100,
                     100.01,
                     max(var_df$layer))))
p
### example 2
meanval <- mean(var_df$layer)
p <- ggplot() 
p <- p + geom_raster(data = var_df , aes(x = x, y = y, fill = layer))
p <- p + coord_equal()

p <- p + scale_fill_gradient2(low = muted("red"), mid = "white",
                              high = muted("blue"), midpoint = meanval)
p
```

[image]

Comment: There's a `breaks` option available in `scale_fill_gradient2`/`scale_fill_gradientn`. Have you tried it ? `scale_fill_gradient2(......, breaks = c(-287,meanval,5000)`.